# Why is `CWnd::UpdateWindow` freezing in this C++ code?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am maintaining an old C++ application using MFC and recently encounter weird freezing in a part that has been working since at least 2018...
I traced the freezing to this code:

```cpp
void CVisBeregning::process_messages()
{
    MSG msg;
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    if (vb->GetSafeHwnd()) {
        vb->UpdateWindow();
    }
}
```

specifically to the `UpdateWindow()` method.

There, `CVisBeregning` is a class derived from `CDialog` and `vb` is its member defined as

```cpp
static CVisBeregning * vb;
```

`vb` is set to be equal to `this` in the class constructor. (I need a global access to the (only) object of that class, since it is used in callbacks from an external code.)

The freeze happens when the first `if` returns `false`, i.e., when there were no messages to process.
It therefore looks like I can avoid it by moving the second `if`-block inside the first one, but I would first like to understand why the freeze happens.

In my particular test case, the `process_messages()` method is called more than 10 times before it freezes, but in on those occasions the first `if` is `true`.
In other words, it seems to crash the first time the `if` is `false`.

*More info*:

The `if (vb->GetSafeHwnd())` check is needed, as the code runs in two modes and in one of them the class does not have any window attached (so the `UpdateWindow()` is never called).

I am using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 x64.

**Edit 2022-09-26:**

The `CVisBeregning` object calls an external program (optimizer/solver called Mosel), in the same thread.
This program has callbacks for different events that are connected to different methods of the `CVisBeregning` class.
The most important are:

- each time Mosel finds a new solution, it calls a method that writes the solution to a text form in the `CVisBeregning` dialog
- every now and then, Mosel fires an `userinterrupt` callback, where the connected `CVisBeregning` method checks whether the user tried to cancel the run, in which case Mosel would stop execution.

The `process_messages()` method was added to both methods as an attempt to prevent Windows marking the dialog window as "Not responding..."

In the cases where `process_messages` does not crash, the call stack when inside has many lines, ending with:

```cpp
>   Gassopt.exe!CVisBeregning::process_messages() Line 647  C++
    Gassopt.exe!CVisBeregning::mi_userinterrupt(Vimactx * ctx, void * libctx) Line 759  C++
    [External Code] 
    Gassopt.exe!CVisBeregning::RunMosel(ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC<char,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char>>> parameters, CDialog * calling_dialog, int inBatchId) Line 448  C++
    Gassopt.exe!CVisBeregning::OnPaint() Line 155   C++
```

On the other hand, right before the freeze the call log includes only three lines, like the code forgot where it came from:

```cpp
>   Gassopt.exe!CVisBeregning::process_messages() Line 653  C++
    Gassopt.exe!CVisBeregning::mi_userinterrupt(Vimactx * ctx, void * libctx) Line 759  C++
    [External Code]
```

Another observation: the call to the external program is done in the `OnPaint()` method of `CVisBeregning` (which does not do anything else). It checks whether the process is running, so there is no danger of calling the program multiple times, but I wander whether overriding `OnPaint()` with a method that does not do any painting is a bad idea?
As far as I can see, the reason for this weird solution is that the `CVisBeregning` object is initiated using its `DoModal()` method and we needed to ensure that `RunMosel()` is run after the window has been activated - should probably have used a message or a timer instead...

Comment: What is the call stack when you break into the debugger when the hang occurs?

Comment: Who calls `process_messages` ? Show that code. Why is `process_messages` needed? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `UpdateWindow()` sends a `WM_PAINT` message if the window's update region is not empty. This will normally call the dialog's `OnPaint()`, or cause its controls to be painted. So something you could do (for debugging) is add the `WM_PAINT` handler for your dialog class, copy there the code from `CDialog::OnPaint()` (in dlgcore.cpp I guess, or search) and analyze it further. Also, `DispatchMessage()` will send the `WM_PAINT` too, so another check you could add is examine if `msg.message==WM_PAINT && msg.hwnd==vb.m_hWnd`, and do not call `UpdateWindow()` in this case, it's not needed.

Comment: How many threads are involved?

Comment: I added more info to the question.
Since `CVisBeregning` overrides `OnPaint()`, I can confirm that a breakpoint there does _not_ trigger once the code enters the "freezing" `UpdateWindow()`.

Comment: So `CVisBeregning::RunMosel` calls explicitely `CVisBeregning::OnPaint`? This is totally wrong. You cannot call `OnPaint` explcicitely.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  No, the other way around: `CVisBeregning::RunMosel()` is called from within `CVisBeregning::OnPaint()` - in fact, all `CVisBeregning::OnPaint()` does is to check whether `CVisBeregning::RunMosel()`  has been called and call it if not.

Comment: Doing something in `OnPaint` that has nothing to do with painting window contents sounds totally wrong.

Comment: So `OnPaint` ends up calling `process_message`, right? Doing a message loop from within a WM_PAINT handler sounds totally wrong to me....

Comment: @Jabberwocky  The first call of `OnPaint` calls `RunMosel`, which takes time to finish. In the meantime, there come new calls to `OnPaint`, but the first one "hangs" there until `RunMosel` finishes - I agree it sounds wrong, that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: I have now removed `RunMosel` from `OnPaint` and call it using a message-based approach from [here](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?527727-DoModal-and-call-function&p=2085597#post2085597) instead. This seems to solve the problem, i.e., `UpdateWindow` does not freeze anymore